# Read a file with InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

So I have a file that has one line of int : 5551212

I am trying to use InputStream to read this file and then see if I can extract the number written within in it

I did the following steps:

```
import java.io.*;

class Shuffle {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream newfile = new FileInputStream("file path");
        System.out.println(newfile.getChannel());
        System.out.println(newfile.getFD()); 
        System.out.println("Number of remaining bytes:"+newfile.available());
        int data;
        while ((data = newfile.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print(data + " ");   
        }
        newfile.close();
    }  
}
```

However, the output that I got is: 53, 53, 53, 49, 50, 49, 50

I am not really sure what this is suppose to represent, or simply how do I use InputStream on integers

Comment: if you just want to parse a number, use a scanner https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Or read a String first,  then use Integer.parse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 11 or above, a file can be read using a single line  of code - ***Files.readString***

**Here is a working example for reading a text file:**

```
// File name:  ReadFile.java

import java.nio.file.*;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path = "my-file.txt";
        // Read file content as a string
        System.out.println(Files.readString(Paths.get(path)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac ReadFile.java

> java ReadFile
   5551212
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you're reading is a text file, and thus the bytes you're receiving are representing encoded chars. If you look at ascii table (eg http://www.asciitable.com/) at decimal value 53, you'll see it's corresponding to a char "5"

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You are reading an int, and the file is text data, not binary. Hence whatever bytes are in the file are interpreted as binary, and you get these numbers.

To read from a text file, you can either use a Scanner, or read as text first and then convert to int.

```
import java.io.*;

class Shuffle {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
             InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(file);
             BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(in)) {
            String line = r.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
                System.out.println(number);
                line = r.readLine();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This code also uses try-with-resources, which makes sure all readers and files are closed at the end, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! This really helped!